# getServerSideProps proper usage?

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch, getserversideprops

I have recently been trying to create a web app with NextJS. I know some basics in web development but I was a little lost when using NextJS as I didn't do any React either before.

I've tried fetching data from an API and using this data in my page. I struggled a bit but in the end I got it working with the help of `getServerSideProps`.

My question is, how could I use `getServerSideProps` multiple times in my application so that I can fetch many other routes ? I've tried using `getServerSideProps` in a different file, using its response in a function that I then export as a component and use it so I can **"get components of getServerSideProps responses"** if it makes sense, but had many different errors when trying to do so.

Could someone explain how it actually works and how I could resolve my issue, and if it doesn't work that way, how could I make it work?

Here's an example using Coinbase's API :

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {

  const res = await fetch('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/ETH-USD/buy')
  const data = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      ethprice: data
    }
  }
};
```

I then use "ethprice" in my Home function such as :

```
export default function Home({ ethprice }) {
  return (
```

[page content, divs, text etc...]

```
  {etherprice.data.amount}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`getServerSideProps` is specific to that particular file, you can't just use it in any way you want.

```
const Example = (props) => {
  return // this is your component
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  // this will provide props specifically for 'Example'
}
```

More than that `getStaticProps` will only be run once on static page generation and never again, along with fetching the props for that particular component only.  So you can't get live data from it, only data required to generate the page (like page title).

You can have a look at `getServerSideProps` if you're looking for something more dynamic that can fetch props at runtime.  After that you can pass those props down to children if you need to.

Comment: Will using ```getServerSideProps``` be working the same as ```getStaticProps```in your example? Or will it behave differently other than that it just runs at build time (I think) ? Mine would probably be more ```getServerSideProps```as I need new informations after refresh and not at build time.

Comment: ````getStaticProps```` is for SSG (static site generation) while ````getServerSideProps```` is for SSR (server side rendering) so it will rerender your page on every request using the data from that function (which is what you want).  However IMO ````getServerSideProps```` should only be used for things like auth where you want it to happen server side, otherwise you should just use a normal client side data fetch for what you want to do.  For that you can use the nextjs API.  https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

Comment: Ohhh okay I get it. I though it was native NextJS (getXProps) and only those could be used and nothing else. I will take a look at the "more regular" routing. Thanks!